# Vallenato Accordion: Nesting Multiple Accordions

Tags: jquery, nested, accordion

I am trying to nest an accordion within an accordion and I need some help. After a few attempts I end up with a nested accordion, but when clicked, instead of it opening it just closes and reverts to the beginning. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example of mark-up

```
<div id="accordion-container"> 
 <h2 class="accordion-header">Section 1</h2> 
 <div class="accordion-content"> 
      <div id="accordion-container"> 
 <h2 class="accordion-header">Nested1 1</h2> 
 <div class="accordion-content"> 
      <p>Nested 1 Content</p> 
 </div> 
 <h2 class="accordion-header">Nested 2</h2> 
 <div class="accordion-content"> 
      <p>Nested 2 Content</p> 
 </div> 
 </div> 
 </div> 
 <h2 class="accordion-header">Section 2</h2> 
 <div class="accordion-content"> 
      <p>Section 2 Content</p> 
 </div> 
 </div>
```

And the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
//Add Inactive Class To All Accordion Headers
$('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

//Set The Accordion Content Width
var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
$('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });

//Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-      header');
$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');

// The Accordion Effect
$('.accordion-header').click(function () {
    if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
        $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    }

    else {
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    }
});

return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, there is a similar question regarding multiple (Vallenato Accordion) accordions on one page... I have changed a bit of the code and how to call it ... I hope this helps.

To call this function....

```
<SCRIPT>
$(window).load(function() { 
    $('#test').simpleAccordion(); 
    $('#test2').simpleAccordion(); 
});
</SCRIPT>
```

..... the jquery code...

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.simpleAccordion = function() {

    var accordId = '#' + $(this).attr('id');

    //Add Inactive Class To All Accordion Headers
    $(accordId + ' .accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

    //Set The Accordion Content Width
    var contentwidth = $(accordId + ' .accordion-header').width();
    $(accordId + ' .accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });

    //Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
    $(accordId + ' .accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
    $(accordId + ' .accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');

    // The Accordion Effect
    $(accordId + ' .accordion-header').click(function () {
        if($(this).is(accordId + ' .inactive-header')) {
            $(accordId + ' .active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        }

        else {
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        }
    });

    return false;
   }; 
})( jQuery );
```